# cakePHP 3 on subdirectory - how to configure?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, httpd.conf

I'm using Wamp. (Bitnami's dist.).

I've used the composer to create the skeleton. and then I've used the cake bake shell to set the MVC files.

Now, when I access `localhost/bookmarker` I get the default cake page that says

> Please be aware that this page will not be shown if you turn off
>   debug mode unless you replace src/Template/Pages/home.ctp with your
>   own version.

If I access `localhost/bookmarker/bookmarks` I see the app. What should I set to change this?

what I want is to access `localhost/bookmarker` and see the app.
Also, I have the same issue (o/c) with a virtual-host that I configures.

Comment: I would suggest to edit your original question... @arod asked the correct question in the comments, the "problem" seems to be your routing configuration.

Comment: thanks. I am about to delete the original, since it seems like i got the "problem" wrong.